# ResultSet return null em Java

Tags: java, postgresql, resultset

Uso o código abaixo para verificar em Postgre se a tabela existe, executando a Query no Pgadmin tenho como valor de resposta null.

Mas aparentemente o ResultSet nunca retornará null. Existe alguma forma de conseguir comparar o RS com null, true or false ? 
Também é possível criar uma nova query, porém preciso saber qual valor o RS ta retornando.

```
Connection conn = Class_Conexao.GetConnection();
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT to_regclass('public.clientes_alter_log')"))
```

Este é trecho que faço a connexão e verifico se existe a Tabela. 
uso um if/else caso exista. 
Alguma idéia de como posso prosseguir ?

Comment: De acordo com o manual a função `to_regclass` pode retornar `NULL`("... These functions differ from a cast from text in that they don't accept a numeric OID, and that they return null rather than throwing an error if the name is not found ... https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html). Uma alternativa é consultar o catálogo: `SELECT EXISTS 
(
 SELECT 1 
 FROM pg_tables
 WHERE schemaname = 'schema_name'
 AND tablename = 'table_name'
);`.

Comment: também usei esse select em outras tabelas, na verdade em todas, li que o toregclass me garante uma resposta mais rápida. Mas o problema é que se ela não existir no banco deve entrar no if(rs.next()) até ai tudo bem, mas quando ela já existe ela deve cair em um else ou algo do tipo, que contem uns stmt exexuteUpdate. porém passa nos 2. E se tiver uma FK cai na exceção

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente na sua `query` você deve atribuir um `alias` à coluna:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT to_regclass('public.clientes_alter_log') AS existencia"));
```

Depois verifique o se o valor da coluna é nulo:

```
if (rs.next()) {
  final String existencia = rs.getString("existencia");
  return !rs.wasNull();
}

return false;
```

---

> [`wasNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull())
>
> Reports whether the last column read had a value of `SQL NULL`. Note that you must first call one of the getter methods on a column to try to read its value and then call the method [`wasNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull()) to see if the value read was `SQL NULL`.

Em tradução livre:

> Informa se a última coluna lida tinha um valor de `SQL NULL`. Observe que você deve primeiro chamar um dos métodos getter em uma coluna para tentar ler seu valor e depois chamar o método [`wasNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull()) para ver se o valor lido foi `SQL NULL`.

Comment: muito interessante, vou tentar obter valor desta forma, pois só pegando o retorno do resultset e usando o rs.next não esta tendo o comportamento que eu espero. Obrigado!

Comment: amigo! muitíssimo obrigado!!! a princípio tive exatamente o resultado que buscava!